# Always failed to close channel (netty) from server-side when the client has been physically killed

Tags: java, websocket, netty, channel

It's a web-socket application based on netty. However, when the client is physically killed without sending a `CloseWebSocketFrame`, server needs to know the channel has been closed and do some cleaning work. `IdleStateHandler` is used to monitor whether the channel is idle.

Here is the channel handler pipeline.

```
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
    SSLEngine sslEngine = new SSLServiceBase().getSSLContext().createSSLEngine();
    sslEngine.setUseClientMode(false);
    sslEngine.setNeedClientAuth(true);
    ... // business process
    pipeline.addLast(new IdleStateHandler(30, 10, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    pipeline.addLast(new HeartbeatHandler());
}
```

This is the `userEventTriggered` method of `HeartbeatHandler` which is used to do some cleaning work when channel is closed from the client abnormally.

```
public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
    if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
        IdleStateEvent event = (IdleStateEvent) evt;
        if (IdleState.WRITER_IDLE.equals(event.state())) {
            ctx.writeAndFlush(new PingWebSocketFrame()).addListener(future -> {
                if (!future.isSuccess()) {
                    ChannelFuture closeFuture = ctx.channel().close();
                    if (closeFuture.isSuccess()) {
                        System.out.println("ping faild, channel close successfully");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("ping failed, channel close failed");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Ping succeed, keep the channel.");
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        super.userEventTriggered(ctx, evt);
    }
}
```

Actually, I'm continuously getting `'close failed'`, and the channel is still alive from the server view. Could anyone let me know why the channel can't be closed or how to close?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the close was not done yet (remember it is an async operation). Change the code to:

```
public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
    if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
        IdleStateEvent event = (IdleStateEvent) evt;
        if (IdleState.WRITER_IDLE.equals(event.state())) {
            ctx.writeAndFlush(new PingWebSocketFrame()).addListener(future -> { 
                if (!future.isSuccess()) {
                    ctx.close().addListener(closeFuture -> {
                        If (closeFuture.isSuccess()) {
                            System.out.println("ping faild, channel close successfully");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("ping failed, channel close failed");
                            // TODO: You may also want to log the reason why the close operation failed. 
                            //       closeFuture.cause() will contain why.
                        }
                    });                    
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Ping succeed, keep the channel.");
                }
        });
    }
} else {
    super.userEventTriggered(ctx, evt);
}
```

}

Comment: I read the most methods of `ChannelFuture` but I missed the `cause()`. Actually there is an Exception happened in method `void close(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelPromise promise)` in one of the `ChannelHandler`, so the channel is failed to close without printing messages. This is the right answer.